# auto update multiple excel file from dropbox in one also in dropbox

Tags: excel, dropbox

I have a dropbox shared folders for 5 users.
Inside that folder there are other folders which contain excel files (multiple sheets).
On top of those multiple sheets is "the one" which accumulate the info for each folder.
At the end I open an ultimate folder which contains a single excel file which must accumulate all "the one"'s as summarize the info.
All files in folders are linked as time "Jan-Jan, Jan- feb...etc" that means for each individual multiple sheets are "sum(offset(...)" and the final one MUST respect the same stuff

Expl: in first excel file I introduce info as"real sales, budget and LY " info and I play as accumulate info Jan-Jan, Jan-Feb, etc....Jan-Dec. The files is working very well and get all info from multiple sheets.
THE BIG ISSUE is when I've try to have a synthesis for all in the last folder which MUST respect the same format JAN-JAN, JAN-FEB....JAN-DEC which the figures from different folders and different/multiple excel files.
All of those are in a shared folder Dropbox.

I HEED UPDATE THE SYNTHESIS ONE W/O OPENING ALL OTHERS!!!!

Comment: So... What is your programming question?

Comment: I don't know what kind of formula I must use?! How shall I introduce?I don't want to open all files to update the synthesis one. That is the question

Comment: If someone need more info please let me know....for me the issue is so urgent and I kill my brain to find a solution!!! Thx in advance for effort too!!!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Excel are you using? I'll assume 2010 in my answer, correct me if necessary.

In the Excel files that have the source data, make sure that the data is introduced in "Tables", formated as such (not Ranges).

Then you should connect the "master" ("the main ones") Excel files to the "slaves" through a MS Query:
Ribbon Data, From Other Sources, From Microsoft Query.
Then Excel files, Ok, locate your file and then the table that has the needed data in the source file (the slave one).

Finally, edit the Connection to set a refresh when you open the master file:
Ribbon Table Tools, Refresh, Connection Properties, Check the checkbox that says "Refresh data when opening the file".

Repeat the process for each slave file and you should be good to go.